# Get one most recent comment for each post in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections in mongodb, one for posts and one for comments. What would be the best approach to get one most recent comment for each post? I'm looking for a similar solution but for mongodb: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Comment: You haven't provided enough information about the structure of your documents in the collections to provide a reasonable answer. For example, I'd strongly suggest you put the most recent comment both in your comments collection AND in the post document so retrieval is optimized. Otherwise, the database is doing a **lot** of extra work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with the aggregation framework by combining [$group](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) with [$max](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/max/#grp._S_max).

I would like to give you an exact solution, but I can't do so unless you give an example of your data.

By the way: The proper way to structure this data in MongoDB would be to put the comments into a sub-Array of the posts.

Comment: +1 even though I put an answer myself, the real problem is a design one, which you pointed out. Comments should be embedded into Post.

Comment: There is no proper way! Each approach has is advantages and disadvantages: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/use-cases/storing-comments/

Comment: @KingJulien absolutely, it depends on what you want to do with comments, but if I were to design a post/comments app, i'd embed the comments array for ease of retrieval.

Comment: Yep, but this is very simplified example and I do some quite complicated operations with these comments and I find it more convenient in this case to store them in separate collection.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else have a similar problem, I solved mine using the Map-Reduce:

First I create a map function like this:

```
$map = "function() { emit(this.post_id, this); }";
```

and reduce function:

```
$reduce = "function(k, vals) {".
            "var newest = null;".
            "for ( var i in vals ) {".
                "if ( newest === null ) {".
                    "newest = vals[i];".
                "}".
                "else {".
                    "if ( vals[i]['_id'] > newest['_id'])".
                        "newest = vals[i]".
                "}".
            "}".
            "return newest;".
        "}";
```

and a new collection with the necessary data is ready...

```
$commentsAggregated = $db->command(array(
        "mapreduce" => "comments",
        "map"       => $map,
        "reduce"    => $reduce,
        "query"     => $query,
        "out"       => array("merge" => "commentsCollectionNew")
    ));

    $getComments = $db->selectCollection($commentsAggregated['result'])->find();
```

Comment: It means your map reduce generates a collection that gets outdated whenever a comment or a post is inserted in the db so you have to keep running the mapreduce to keep the generated collection updated instead of using a query, I think.

Comment: Yes, @JoeMinichino is correct. Unlike some NoSql options, MapReduces aren't automatically updated in MongoDb.